# SOLR MYSQL import with MYSQL ROUND()

Tags: mysql, solr

Hi I'm attempting to import a price field from my mysql DB into solr.

However the price does not have tax included and needs to be rounded to 2 decimal places.

I have attempted to use the following in my dat-config.xml

```
  <document>
    <entity name="uc_products" query="SELECT ROUND((sell_price * 1.2),2) AS sell_price FROM uc_products WHERE sell_price > 0"></entity>
  </document>
```

The sql query works fine normally, but solr isn't processing it.  Solr doesn't appear to be giving any errors, the import just hangs forever.

Comment: Have you tried using the dataimport admin page (http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport)? it has options to debug and see trace.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out nothing was wrong with this setup, just my index had somehow become corrupted and was messing everything up.

To solve I stopped tomcat, deleted the data/index folder (the various delete commands on the web didn't seem to be working).  Restarted tomcat and it's working with this import.